# Why does PostgreSQL complain about timestamp '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Per the [Postgres manual on date/time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), the `timestamp` type can go from 4713 BC to a bazillion years in the future. So, why does Pg complain that '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not a valid timestamp?

Comment: At this date, the `Big Bang` did not occur yet.

Comment: ouch, ouch, ouch... Let's leave it there as evidence that there are indeed silly questions. <embarrassed>

Comment: Fixed the link. Please don't link to dead versions versions of the manual. [PostgreSQL 8.2 has reached end of life last year](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). [Consider this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

00 is not a valid month number or day number.

Comment: 0000 is not a valid year, either.

Answer (score 8):

You may be thinking of:

```
'allballs'::time
```

Which is the same as:

```
'00:00:00'::time
```

Works for data type `time`, but *not* for a `timestamp`.
If you are looking for the **smallest possible timestamp** value, use:

```
'-infinity'::timestamp
```

Which is, [per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) ...

> earlier than all other time stamps

Comment: 0_0  That has to be one of the most bizarre built-in functions that I've ever seen.  Honestly, if you hadn't provided the documentation link and if I hadn't tried it myself, I wouldn't have believed that PostgreSQL would include something called `allballs`.

Comment: @JackManey: I had a good laugh, too, when I first came across it. It's a historic thing. Back in the day, there were also `z` and `zulu` for the same purpose, but those got dropped with Postgres 7.4. The reason behind it: on old systems it was kind of hard to tell 'O' (the letter) from '0' (the digit).

Answer (score 2):

What timestamp could have a month or day of `00`?